# How can I use JSON data to populate the options of a select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to feed cities based on country of selection. I did it programmically but have no idea how to put JSON data into the select box. I tried several ways using jQuery, but none of them worked.

The response I am getting (I can format this differently if necessary):

```
["<option value='Woodland Hills'>Woodland Hills<\/option>","<option value='none'>none<\/option>","<option value='Los Angeles'>Los Angeles<\/option>","<option value='Laguna Hills'>Laguna Hills<\/option>"]
```

But how can I put this data as options inside a HTML `<select></select>` tag?

The code I tried:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input id="city" name="city" type="text" onkeyup="getResults(this.value)"/>
<input type="text" id="result" value=""/>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect" ><option selected="selected">blank</option></select>
</form>
</div>

<script>
function getResults(str) {
  $.ajax({
        url:'suggest.html',
        type:'POST',
        data: 'q=' + str,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( json ) {
            $('#myselect').append(json);

        }
    });
};

$( '.suggest' ).keyup( function() {
   getResults( $( this ).val() );
} );
</script>
```

I also tried to use this [tutorial on auto-populating select boxes using jQuery and AJAX](http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/), but this never did anything except filling my select with "UNDEFINED" for me even though I got the response in the format the tutorial suggested.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
  $("select#city").change(function(){
    $.getJSON("/select.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
      }
      $("select#myselect").html(options);
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 101):

Why not just make the server return the names?

```
["Woodland Hills", "none", "Los Angeles", "Laguna Hills"]
```

Then create the `<option>` elements using JavaScript.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'suggest.html',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'q=' + str,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: One more thing, how do yo clean existing options before you append yours?

Comment: I found this solution
$('#mySelect')[0].options.length = 0;
 unless someone knows better one

Comment: Do you see a simple way to also select one of the options?

Comment: @Dennis: You can add the `selected` attribute. With jQuery, I believe you use `.prop('selected', true)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shouldn't be the type 'GET', though?

Answer (score 28):

Given returned json from your://site.com:

```
[{text:"Text1", val:"Value1"},
{text:"Text2", val:"Value2"},
{text:"Text3", val:"Value3"}]
```

Use this:

```
    $.getJSON("your://site.com", function(json){
            $('#select').empty();
            $('#select').append($('<option>').text("Select"));
            $.each(json, function(i, obj){
                    $('#select').append($('<option>').text(obj.text).attr('value', obj.val));
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 18):

You should do it like this:

```
function getResults(str) {
  $.ajax({
        url:'suggest.html',
        type:'POST',
        data: 'q=' + str,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( json ) {
           $.each(json, function(i, optionHtml){
              $('#myselect').append(optionHtml);
           });
        }
    });
};
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JQuery view engine](https://jocapc.github.io/jquery-view-engine/) and just load the array into a dropdown:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'suggest.html',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'q=' + str,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
          // Assumption is that API returned something like:["North","West","South","East"];
          $('#myselect').view(json);
    }
});
```

See details here: https://jocapc.github.io/jquery-view-engine/docs/ajax-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

zeusstl is right. it works for me too.

```
   <select class="form-control select2" id="myselect">
                      <option disabled="disabled" selected></option>
                      <option>Male</option>
                      <option>Female</option>
                    </select>

   $.getJSON("mysite/json1.php", function(json){
        $('#myselect').empty();
        $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text("Select"));
        $.each(json, function(i, obj){

  $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(obj.text).attr('value', obj.val));
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I'd use a jQuery template and a $.ajax call:

```
ASPX:
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect>
    <option value="0">-select-</option>
</select>
<script id="mySelectTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <option value="${CityId}">${CityName}</option>
</script>

JS:
$.ajax({ 
    url: location.pathname + '/GetCities', 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function (response) { 
        $('#mySelectTemplate').tmpl(response.d).appendTo('#mySelect'); 
    } 
});
```

In addition to the above you'll need a web method (GetCities) that returns a list of objects that include the data elements you're using in your template.  I often use Entity Framework and my web method will call a manager class that is getting values from the database using linq.  By doing that you can have your input save to the database and refreshing your select list is as simple as calling the databind in JS in the success of your save.