# Populate dropdown from json response

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I want to populate my dropdown with json data.

```
<select id="selectSkill"><option>Choose a skill</option></select>
```

I have **json** in following format:

```
[
  {
    "SkillID": "100",
    "SkillName": "301 - COMCAST"
  },
  {
    "SkillID": "36",
    "SkillName": "303 - COX"
  },
]
```

In case of normal arrays, I would do it like this:

```
var array= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
$.each(array, function (i, p) {
$('#selectSkill').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
```

How would I populate my dropdown as to set `SkillID` as value and `SkillName` as text of my dropdown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use JSON data to populate the options of a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918144/how-can-i-use-json-data-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-box)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost there. Just get the data from the object (`p` in your code is an object)

You can do:-

```
$.each(array, function (i, p) {
  $('#selectSkill').append($('<option></option>').val(p.SkillID).html(p.SkillName));
});
```

Working example:-

```js
array =[
  {
    "SkillID": "100",
    "SkillName": "301 - COMCAST"
  },
  {
    "SkillID": "36",
    "SkillName": "303 - COX"
  },
];

$.each(array, function (i, p) {
  $('#selectSkill').append($('<option></option>').val(p.SkillID).html(p.SkillName));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectSkill"></select>
```

Comment: Perfect and simple!