# How to call ajax data correctly

Tags: php, ajax

I have a database table name country & states I am trying to call states when country is selected every sates has associated country column name XX like for Pakistan PK, for United States of America US and so on my code examples are below to find a solution.

**Country Select Box**

```
<select name="country" id="country">
<option value="-1">Select Country</option>
<?php
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `country`");
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['country_code'].'">';
            echo $row['country_name'];
        echo '</option>';
    }
?>
```

**State Select Box**

```
<select name="country" id="states">
<option value="-1">Select State</option>
</select>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country').on('change',function(){
        var countryCode = $(this).val();
        if(countryCode){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'getStates.php',
                data: {countryCode:country_code},
                success:function(data){
                    $("#states").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I have the separate file where I am fetching states with ajax

```
<?php include_once("inc/config.php");?>
<option value="-1">Select State</option>
<?php
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `state` WHERE `country_code` = '".$_POST['country_code']."' ");
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) ){
        echo '<option value="';
            $row['state_id'];
        echo '">';
            echo $row['state_name'];
        echo '</option>';
    }
?>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
```

**Note:**
Database connection is ok because when I insert `'PK'` instead of `'".$_POST['country_code']."'` in getStates.php file it works fine and when I insert `console.log()` in ajax `success:function(data){console.log()}` it shows related value of country but I think I am doing some mistake somewhere in ajax code.

I also get an undefined variable error when I insert `$_POST['country_code']` or `$_POST['countryCode']` in getStates.php file.

*I am sure there is something wrong in ajax call*

Comment: You might want to also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918144/how-can-i-use-json-data-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-box if I'd answered I would have included this

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to send `country_code` as a value. But you haven't declared the variable. Try:

```
data: {'countryCode':countryCode},
```

Also: you might want to add some security checks before using a variable posted by your user in a query. Have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: NOw I am getting ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: countryCode in path/to/getStates.php on line X I am using $_POST['CountryCode'] in getStates.php file

Comment: Just found a solution https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp now everything is working fine.